# Cannot take of the value of text field when the link is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.1.60/json_android/getItemData.php",
        jsonpCallback: 'item',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            var markup = "";
            $.each(data.list, function(i, elem) {
                var $template = $('<li>    <div class=ui-grid-a>   <div class=ui-block-a>  </div>  <div class=ui-block-b>    </div>  </div>   </li>');

                $template.find(".ui-block-a").append('<a href=#  id=' + elem['itemId'] + '>' + elem['itemId'] + '</a>');
                $template.find(".ui-block-b").append("<input type=text/>")
 markup += $template.html();

            });
            $("#tweet-list").append(markup).listview("refresh", true);

        },
        error: function(request, error) {
            alert(error);

        }
    });



$('#tweet-list').on('click', 'a', function(event) {

   console.log($(this).closest("input[type=text]").val());
});
```

Here I want to get the value of the text field associated with link when the link is clicked. I tried above code but it does not work properly.

Comment: you mean `$(this).closest('div').next('div').find('input').val();`?

Comment: actually i need to take value of the text field next to the link clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're structure looks like this

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Mobile will enhance contents, so the structure will look different after rendering:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">First</span></span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c">
      <input type="text" value="First button - first input" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use the below to retrieve input value

```
$(this).closest('div').next('.ui-block-b').find('input').val();
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/m2LRf/)**